# Re-enabled the all notifications

Tags: 16.04, notification

I want to stop the VLC pop-up notification. so I had fired this command,

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service{,.disabled}
```

after firing this command my all notifications are stopped so how can i re-enabled it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert the file name using :

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service{.disabled,}
```